# Won't read from file to struct

Tags: c, file, struct

I've been sitting with this problem for 2 days and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried debugging (kind of? Still kind of new), followed this link: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ And I've tried Google and all kinds of things. Basically I'm reading from a file with this format:

R1  Fre     17/07/2015   18.00     FCN - SDR     0 - 2     3.211

and I have to make the program read this into a struct, but when I try printing the information it comes out all wrong. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_INPUT 198

typedef struct game{
    char   weekday[4],
           home_team[4],
           away_team[4];
    int    round,
           hour,
           minute,
           day,
           month,
           year,
           home_goals,
           away_goals,
           spectators;}game;

game make_game(FILE *superliga);

int main(void){
    int    input_number,
           number_of_games = 198,
           i = 0;
    game   tied[MAX_INPUT];

    FILE *superliga;
    superliga = fopen("superliga-2015-2016.txt", "r");

    for(i = 0; i < number_of_games; ++i){
                tied[i] = make_game(superliga);
                printf("R%d %s %d/%d/%d %d.%d %s - %s %d - %d %d\n",
                        tied[i].round, tied[i].weekday, tied[i].day, tied[i].month,
                        tied[i].year, tied[i].hour, tied[i].minute, tied[i].home_team,
                        tied[i].away_team, tied[i].home_goals, tied[i].away_goals,
                        tied[i].spectators);}

 fclose(superliga);

 return 0;
}

game make_game(FILE *superliga){
    double spect;
    struct game game_info;

    fscanf(superliga, "R%d %s %d/%d/%d %d.%d %s - %s %d - %d %lf\n",
            &game_info.round, game_info.weekday, &game_info.day, &game_info.month,
            &game_info.year, &game_info.hour, &game_info.minute, game_info.home_team,
            game_info.away_team, &game_info.home_goals, &game_info.away_goals,
            &spect);

         game_info.spectators = spect * 1000;

    return game_info;
 }
```

Comment: I think the `\n` could cause a problem in the `fscanf`

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code line by line. And check what [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns.

Comment: Text file data parsing in C sucks.  I feel for you having to do this, if it helps.  Know that other languages give you much better tools for this when you get there.

Comment: What comes out all wrong? What is the output you are getting?

Comment: Elyasin, a lot of lines looking like this:

R19528456 X a 1952502352/6422476/0 1952598979.271333979 EKbt? - ? 93 - 6412588 -2147483648

Comment: Jean-Francois Fabre, unfortunately that wasn't it.

Some programmer dude, any recommendations? 

Michael Dorgan, haha, thanks man, it's somewhat of a comfort.

Comment: You give an example of what "a lot" of lines come out looking like - but is the first line of the output correct?

Comment: Try replacing the the \n with a space. Show us the first three lines of the input file.

Comment: @lyst, none of the output lines are correct. This is some of the lines printed: http://imgur.com/a/WFGZS

Comment: @johnelemans, replacing the \n with a space does nothing, unfortunately. The first three lines of the input file are:

 R1  Fre     17/07/2015   18.00     FCN - SDR     0 - 2     3.211 -----------------  R1  Lor     18/07/2015   16.00     FCM - VFF     2 - 0     7.232 -----------------  R1  Son     19/07/2015   13.30     OB - HOB      3 - 0     7.797

Comment: Can you by any chance upload the `superliga-2015-2016.txt` file somewhere?

Comment: I suspect your data file. I compiled your code and ran it with the first three lines that you posted above and it reads all data correctly (with the \n in the format).

Comment: Any chance your data file is UTF8 or something like it?  That would cause your output to be wrong as soon as a non ASCII code came through.

Comment: @yurilaguardia Here's a link to the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Moe8yx6nyCZENpWjM5SS0tbm8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

If each line in the file is a separate record, you should read each line as a string, then try to parse each string.

(Note that this also has the added feature of *speculative parsing*: you can try parsing the line in several different formats, and accept the one that parses correctly. I like to use this when I accept e.g. vector inputs, so that the user can use `x y z`, `x, y, z`, `x/y/z`, `(x,y,z)`, `[x,y,z]`, `<x y z>`, `<x,y,z>`, and so on, depending on what they like. It's only one additional scanf per format, after all.)

To read lines, you can use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) into a local buffer. The local buffer must be long enough. If the program is to run on POSIX.1 machines only (i.e., not on Windows), then you can use [`getline()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) instead, which can dynamically reallocate the given buffer as needed, so you're not limited to any specific line length.

To parse the string, use [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html).

Note that all tabs, spaces, and newlines in the pattern in all of the scanf family of functions are treated exactly the same: they indicate any number of any type of whitespace. In other words, `\n` does not mean *"and then a newline"*; it means the same as a space, i.e. *"and possibly some whitespace here"*. However, all conversions except `%c` and `%[` automatically skip any leading whitespace; so, with the exception of a space before one of those two, the spaces in the pattern are only meaningful to us humans, they do not have any functional effect in the scanning.

All scanf family of functions return the number of successful conversions. (The only exception is the "conversion" `%n`, which yields the number of characters consumed; some implementations include it in the conversion count, and some others do not.) If end of input occurs prior to the first conversion, or a read error occurs, or the input does not match with the fixed part of the pattern, the functions will return `EOF`.

Even if you suppress saving the result of a conversion -- for example, if you have a word in the input you don't need, you can convert but discard it with `%*s` --, it is counted. So, for example `sscanf(line, " %*d %*s %*d")` returns 3 if the line starts with an integer, followed by a word (anything that is not a newline nor contains whitespace), followed by an integer.

Rather than have the function return the parsed structure, pass a pointer to the structure (and the file handle to read from), and return a status code. I prefer `0` for success, and nonzero for failure, but feel free to change that.

In other words, I'd suggest you change your read function into

```
#ifndef  GAME_LINE_MAX
#define  GAME_LINE_MAX   1022
#endif

int read_game(game *one, FILE *in)
{
    char  buffer[GAME_LINE_MAX + 2]; /* + '\n' + '\0' */
    char *line;

    /* Sanity check: no NULL pointers accepted! */
    if (!one || !in)
        return -1;

    /* Paranoid check: Fail if read error has already occurred. */
    if (ferror(in))
        return -1;

    /* Read the line */
    line = fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, in);
    if (!line)
        return -1;

    /* Parse the game; pattern from OP's example: */
    if (sscanf(line, "R%d %3s %d/%d/%d %d.%d %3s - %3s %d - %d %d\n",
                     &(one->round), one->weekday,
                     &(one->day), &(one->month), &(one->year),
                     &(one->hour), &(one->minute)
                     one->home_team,
                     one->away_team,
                     &(one->home_goals),
                     &(one->away_goals),
                     &(one->spectators)) < 12)
        return -1; /* Line not formatted like above */

    /* Spectators in the file are in units of 1000; convert: */
    one->spectators *= 1000;

    /* Success. */
    return 0;
}
```

To use the above function in a loop, reading games one after another from standard input (`stdin`):

```
game  g;

while (!read_game(&g, stdin)) {

    /* Do something with current game stats, g */

}

if (ferror(stdin)) {

    /* Read error occurred! */

} else
if (!feof(stdin)) {

    /* Not all data was read/parsed! */

}
```

The two `if` clauses above are to check if there was a real read error (as in, a problem with the hardware or something like that), and whether there was unread/unparsed data (not at end of file), respectively.

There are two differences in the scanning pattern compared to the OP: First, all strings parsed are limited to 3 characters, because the structure has only room for 3+1 each. The one character is reserved for the end of string `'\0'`, which is not counted in the maximum length for `%s`. Second, I parse the spectator count directly, and just multiply the field by 1000 if successful.

Also note how I used `one->weekday`, `one->home_team`, and `one->away_team` to refer to the character arrays. This works, because an array variable can be used as if it was a pointer to the first element in that array. (Given `char a[5];`, `a` and `&a` and `&(a[0])` can all be used to refer to the first element in the array `a`). I like to use this "raw form" when scanning, because it makes it easier to match them to `%s` conversions, and ensure the pattern matches the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I changed it and changed '*one' to '*g', because of some errors. Unfortunately, I'm now getting an error I don't know how to deal with: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'game {aka struct game}' from type 'int': tied[i] = read_game(g, in);

Comment: @NikolajAB: Thanks; I corrected the function example. I added a paragraph or two before the code snippet as an explanation, as well as an example of use. Basically, instead of returning a `game` structure, you need to pass a pointer to it; the function will return `0` if success, and nonzero if it fails. In other words, use `if (read_game(&(tied[i]), in)) { /* Could not read game! */ } else { /* Game read successfully */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your file. It starts with whitespaces, not with `R`'s as you stated in the control string.

Check the return value of `fscanf()` and you'll see that it's zero everytime.

If you add a leading whitespace to your fscanf() call, your problem will be solved, like this:

```
fscanf(superliga, " R%d %s %d/%d/%d %d.%d %s - %s %d - %d %lf\n",
            &game_info.round, game_info.weekday, &game_info.day, &game_info.month,
            &game_info.year, &game_info.hour, &game_info.minute, game_info.home_team,
            game_info.away_team, &game_info.home_goals, &game_info.away_goals,
            &spect);
```

Comment: I tried adding a whitespace and I get the same weird output.

Comment: Are you sure? Here your program works perfectly after that one change.

Comment: Goddamn, just tried copying my code from here and into a new file instead of editing my old one and it worked! Thank you so much! How frustrating that such a small thing can cause so much grief!